# Approximate data of N elements as a sum of products of the target

Tags: matrices, data-analysis, monte-carlo, data-mining

Computer Engineer here. I need help with a personal project that is data science related. I am trying to approximate how to solve something like this. Each of these values are a PCA(principle component analysis value).
I have dozens of equations in the form of (let's say with 5 variables but I need to be able to solve for 10 or 20 or 30 or 40)-

```
Target -
0.0694,0.01218,-0.1044,0.0723,-0.0717

A-
0.045529,0.066009,-0.151885,0.002664,-0.125023
B-
0.0785,-0.02538,0.03959,0.186049,-0.068936
C-
0.1253,0.11580,0.05726,0.07892,0.0113
D-
0.10585,-0.06042,0.09748,0.1992,-0.0826
E-
-0.0070176,-0.247268,-0.2299763,0.165638,-0.0353688
```

I need to be able to solve this in a manner where a possible solution would be (or better/ lower Euclidean distance)-

```
Solution =
48.4 A
24.6 C
19.0 E
5.8 B
2.2 D

Edit:So here the target is solved as - 48.4*A + 24.6*C + 19.0 *E + 5.8*B + 2.2*D = Target
```

The solution is at a **Euclidean distance of 0.0135** from the target. I know there are solutions using Monte Carlo where they use penalties and cycles. I don't understand Monte Carlo well. Some folks are using machine learning algorithms.

I need help with what kind of algorithm I can use; as well as required reading to understand the math behind this. The aim is to find a better solution than a local minima, hopefully the absolute minima but it needs to something that can be done fairly quickly on a PC (few seconds and not hours).

I haven't been in touch with Math for many years so I am pretty lost.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: It is not clear what problem it is that you are trying to solve. Also, I know what PCA is, but what is a "PCA value"?

Comment: I am trying to solve the Target. So here the target is solved as - 48.4*A + 24.6*C + 19.0 *E + 5.8*B + 2.2*D = T. This solution is at 0.0135 Euclidean distance from the Target's value.

Comment: I have found some resources like - https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mmahoney/talks/data1.pdf http://parallel.bas.bg/dpa/BG/dimov/MyPapers/98DA.pdf . However, I am not sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: It looks like what you're really after is the [least squares solution](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf) to a system of equations

Comment: Thank you @Omnomnomnom ! I'll check it out.